# How to install an adhoc app through itunes in Windows if it's name has an accent

Tags: iphone, installation, itunes, adhoc

Let's say I have an app called: "my ápp" (i.e. set in PRODUCT_NAME under build tab)

If I try to install it app works in Mac but not on Windows (XP).

Itunes on Windows throws an error: "Application "my ápp" could not install[...] unknown error[...]"

If I remove the accent from the app name, that is: "my app", it works. 
It seems there's some problems with the special chars encoding.

Any idea?

Saludos!

---

Could solve the problem! 
It seems that the accent written in Mac is interpreted with strange simbols by Windows, so by simply renaming in Windows the .app directory and the file inside (with the same name) with the accent it can be installed with no problems.

Hope this helps to someone else.